# Easiest way to move a commit in the commit history on the same branch

Tags: git, github

I would like to be able to easily take commits from anywhere in my commit history and make them the most recent commit *on the same branch*. I would prefer to use the git command line tools for this, but I'm open to GUI tools as well.

I investigated `git-cherry-pick`, but from my understanding of the docs and my own testing, cherry-picking an existing commit makes the cherry-picked (most recent) commit empty because it already exists in the history.

You can assume that there won't be conflicts, since my need for this comes from following the development strategy outlined in [these](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabflavor/article/recommendations_on_revision_control/) [articles](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabflavor/article/writing_reviewable_code/). Even if there were, I would be fine with correcting them as needed.

**EDIT:** I found a solution using interactive rebasing. I've posted it as an answer to this question, but I'm curious to see what other solutions there are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fairly simple solution I discovered is using the interactive rebase mode of [git-rebase](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) to reorder the commits. On invoking `git rebase -i HEAD~3` to rebase the three most recent commits before HEAD, this appears (with my own annotations commented with a `#`):

```
pick 57c3e7e [bug 972919] Removed outdated information from the readme
pick 9390105 [bug 972919] Cleaned up app.js
pick 626e865 [bug 972919] Removed CORS logic

# Git provides standard instructions for the use of this mode in comments
# below the commits you've selected
```

By shifting the line of the commit I want to the bottom of that list, it reorders it to be the most recent in the history when the rebase is concluded:

```
pick 9390105 [bug 972919] Cleaned up app.js
pick 626e865 [bug 972919] Removed CORS logic
pick 57c3e7e [bug 972919] Removed outdated information from the readme # <-- this one will be most recent
```

Answer (score 1):

`git rebase -i HEAD~NumberOfCommits`
Where `NumberOfCommits` is the amount of commits you want to inspect.

Git will open editor with the list of commits where you may choose to edit, squash or skip any of the commits. If you want to remove a commit you delete the line:

```
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#    
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
```

Note that your branch will be different from remote when you do this, so you will have to forcedly push and if anyone else has a copy of the old history it will be necessary to do a hard reset to the new history.

Please read the subchapter [The Perils of Rebasing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing#The-Perils-of-Rebasing). It got a much better explanation than I can provide.

Comment: Thanks for the response. As a nit, interactive mode of a rebase doesn't have a `skip` command - one has to delete the line representing that commit to accomplish what you're suggesting.